# cordova-plugin-contacts name search via phone number

Tags: ios, cordova, search, plugins, contacts

I recently tried to use the cordova contact plugin to find a contact name.
search parameter is a phone number. I found out, that iOS is formatting the phone number like +1 23 223 2222.
I was searching for "2232222". Having a look at the source code I saw, that the contact plugin doesn't remove the whitepsaces before it compares with the search string and therefore the contact will never be found.
Is this a wanted behavior? am I the only one struggling with this "feature" or is there a known workaround for that - without changing the source?

Cheers
Chris

Comment: here is the piece of code in contact.m where my search fails: `NSPredicate* containPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", testValue];`

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the issue and I have found a fix.
If you replace the space that you would have in a phone number with this unicode character: \u00a0 you will get the correct result.

I believe the 'space' in the numbers is not an actual space, but a unicode character.

My numbers look like this: 07900 255XXX.

There is a gotcha though: my testing so far has shown inconsistent results. 
If I edit the phone contact and remove the space and then save the contact, the phone will put it back and the contact will show up in a search ( I assume it replaces the space with this character).

Some other contacts show up without replacing this in the search, but won't show up if I do. I can only assume I have contacts in both 'formats'. A step in the right direction for you as well I hope, for me it works, I will just search one, if no result ... try the other.